# Conditionally split rows based on value in a specific column

Tags: r

I would like to convert the columns below into the format below this. The way the reformatting works is that the sample is grouped between sample type N. For example the first two rows below are grouped together, and 7397-DNA_A01 to 7399-DNA_A01 is grouped together.

```
  Sample     Sample Type    
7393.DNA_A01    N
7394-DNA_A01    T
7395-DNA_A01    N
7396-DNA_A01    T
7397-DNA_A01    N
7398-DNA_A01    T
7399-DNA_A01    LN
7400-DNA_A01    N
7401-DNA_A01    T
7402-DNA_A01    B


  desired output
      N               T           B              LN
 7393.DNA_A01  7394-DNA_A01
 7395-DNA_A01  7396-DNA_A01
 7397-DNA_A01  7398-DNA_A01                   7399-DNA_A01
 7400-DNA_A01  7401-DNA_A01    7402-DNA_A01
```

I'm really not sure how to split the rows when N is encountered and then I suppose I would need to transpose somehow. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

We need to create a grouping index ('indx') based on the occurence of 'N'.  Here, a logical vector was created (`SampleType=='N'`) and `cumsum` it to create the 'indx'.  Based on the order of the columns, it may be useful to change the 'SampleType' column to `factor` and specify the levels as in the order of column names in the expected result.  Then we can use `dcast` from either `reshape2` or `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setDT(df1)[, indx:=cumsum(SampleType=='N')
    ][, SampleType:= factor(SampleType, levels=c('N', 'T', 'B', 'LN'))]

dcast(df1, indx~SampleType, value.var='Sample', fill='')[,-1,with=FALSE]
#          N            T            B           LN
#1: 7393.DNA_A01 7394-DNA_A01                          
#2: 7395-DNA_A01 7396-DNA_A01                          
#3: 7397-DNA_A01 7398-DNA_A01              7399-DNA_A01
#4: 7400-DNA_A01 7401-DNA_A01 7402-DNA_A01
```

If you are using `dcast` from `reshape2`, the 'indx' column can be created by `base R` options.  You can also change the 'SampleType' column to `factor` using a similar code as below.

```
 df1$indx <- cumsum(df1$SampleType=='N')
 library(reshape2)
 dcast(df1, indx~SampleType, value.var='Sample', fill='')
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Sample = c("7393.DNA_A01", "7394-DNA_A01",
"7395-DNA_A01", 
"7396-DNA_A01", "7397-DNA_A01", "7398-DNA_A01", "7399-DNA_A01", 
"7400-DNA_A01", "7401-DNA_A01", "7402-DNA_A01"), SampleType = c("N", 
"T", "N", "T", "N", "T", "LN", "N", "T", "B")), .Names = c("Sample", 
"SampleType"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: Thanks akrun. I keep on getting the error that dcast is not available for the data.table library. I tried updating the package but I still get 1.9.4 How can I use reshape2 to do this instead?

Comment: @MarkPusung It is from the devel version v1.9.5.  You can find the instructions to install from [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

Comment: Try `dcast.data.table`?